# Sentiment analysis using TextBlob for Dutch language

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, translation, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I want to do sentiment analysis of a list of tweets fetched based on a particular keyword. The tweets coming in are mostly in dutch language and TextBlob needs them converted to English in order to compute the tweet's polarity and subjectivity value. How can I convert the tweet to English language? I basically need a FREE API to do the translation. Having trouble using the MS Bing Translator. I have tried using `goslate` , `langdetect` , `translate` and `translation` libraries but none of them worked. Here's the code that I am using :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy
import goslate
from langdetect import detect
from translation import baidu, google, youdao, iciba
from translate import Translator
import os
import time
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
t=time.time()
#karan's api keys 
consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_key = 'xxx'
access_secret = 'xxx'

gs=goslate.Goslate()
translator= Translator(to_lang="en")
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_results = api.search(q="football", count=2, geocode="52.132633,5.2912659999999505,300km")
f=open('tweets_football.txt','wb')

for i in range(0,len(search_results)):
    try:
        print search_results[i].text        
        print search_results[i].id
        print search_results[i].user.screen_name
        trans=search_results[i].text
        #print(gs.translate(trans,'en'))
        print(translator.translate(trans))
        if search_results[i].text not in search_results:
            f.write(search_results[i].text)
            f.write("\n")
            print "Written to file!"
    except Exception as e:
         print str(e)



f.close()
print time.time()-t
```

Please point me in the right direction. If there's an easier method for this process, please suggest that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title of the question isn't the real question. You're basically just looking for a free Dutch to English translator right?

Comment: I already found a free Dutch to English translator api to use. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

from translate import Translator
from googletrans import Translator

text = 'hallo_allemaal'

entext = Translator().translate(text, src='nl',dest='en').text

print(entext)

Google API has some limitations of number of hits from one IP. if you get that error. Check out for that too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ducth package for **textblob** as `textblob-nl`. You can install it via `pip install textblob`

Official sample:

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
    from textblob_nl import PatternTagger, PatternAnalyzer
    text = u"De kat wil wel vis eten maar geen poot nat maken."
    blob = TextBlob(text, pos_tagger=PatternTagger(), analyzer=PatternAnalyzer())
    blob.sentiment
    >>> (-0.1, 0.4)
```

You can find more information: https://github.com/gvisniuc/textblob-nl